# Java - Loop gets executed, but header doesnt fit condition

Tags: java, loops, libgdx

This function should check if the explosion hit a box and should be canceled on the first box it hits.

For example bsp.getBomb().getStrength() is currently 2, when a box is hit i=3, but the loop is executed one more time even if the condition isn't met, why is that?

```
    public void detectBomb(BombSpritePair bsp) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= bsp.getBomb().getStrength(); i++) {
        if(bd.detect(bsp.getBomb().getX(), bsp.getBomb().getY()+i)) {           
            Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("gras.png"));
            sprite.setPosition(bsp.getBomb().getX()*16, (bsp.getBomb().getY()+i)*16);
        //  i = bsp.getBomb().getStrength()+1;
            sprites.add(sprite);
            System.out.println("RIP"+i);
            System.out.println(bsp.getBomb().getStrength());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're using `<=` instead of the correct `<`.

Comment: That doesn't matter...3<=2 shouldnt work

Comment: is `bsp.getBomb().getStrength()` constant the whole time the loop is running?  Changing loop bounds during execution of the loop is often a Bad Thing. **Plus**, you are changing `i` within the body of the loop.  Also not a good thing!

Comment: i = bsp.getBomb().getStrength()+1; so i=3

Comment: @cwx yes it is constant while the loop is running, at least for this test

Comment: If your `if` boolean evaluates to `true`, then yes.

Comment: Anyway, welcome to the site!  Please see the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more information about asking questions that are likely to receive helpful answers.  For this code, I suggest rethinking your logic so you don't have to change `i` during the loop.

Comment: @Zircon yes it is true

Comment: @cxw even when i use a break it gets executed 2 times

Comment: Try just removing the `i=...` line and see what happens.  If you have added a `break`, please edit the question to show the updated code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `break` to the loop:

```
public void detectBomb(BombSpritePair bsp) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= bsp.getBomb().getStrength(); i++) {
        if(bd.detect(bsp.getBomb().getX(), bsp.getBomb().getY() + i)) {           
            Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("gras.png"));
            sprite.setPosition(bsp.getBomb().getX()*16, (bsp.getBomb().getY()+i)*16);
            sprites.add(sprite);
            System.out.println("RIP"+i);
            System.out.println(bsp.getBomb().getStrength());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You may be seeing duplicate print statements if you are calling the `detectBomb` method multiple times. Putting a breakpoint or print statement at the beginning of this method will help determine what the problem is.

Another thing to keep in mind is that you are creating a new Texture for the Sprite every time the method get executed - it would be wise to only instantiate the Texture once and share it with all subsequent Sprite instances that require it.

Comment: Are you calling `detectBomb` more than once?

Comment: I'm calling it in a render method, so yes